# Populate Select2 from function call with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to populate a select2 dropdown with an AJAX response function with data that will be called whenever the dropdown required for it changes value. I console logged to be sure that the function gets reached, but nonetheless, the instructions are not being ran by the machine:

**create.tpl - Holds front-end code**

```
    $('.select2lead').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/modules/support/ajaxLeadSearch.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data,
                    more: false
                };
            }
        }
    });

    $('.select2lead').on("change", function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
        // console.log(value);
        searchProjectsByLeadID(value);
    });

    function searchProjectsByLeadID(id){
        $('.select2project').select2({
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/modules/support/ajaxProjectSearch.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: {
                    "id": id
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data,
                        more: false
                    };
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(id);
    }
```

**ajaxProjectSearch.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../../config.php');

$login = new Login();
if (!$login->checkLogin()) {
    echo lang($_SESSION['language'], "INSUFFICIENT_RIGHTS");
    exit();
}

$db = new Database();

// Select the projects
$query = "
                    SELECT
                        ProjectID AS project_id,
                        ProjectSummaryShort AS project_summary,
                    FROM
                        `rapports_projectTBL`
                    INNER JOIN LeadTBL ON rapports_projectTBL.LeadID=LeadTBL.LeadID
                    WHERE
                        ProjectID > 0
                    AND
                        rapports_projectTBL.LeadID LIKE :leadId
                    ORDER BY
                        ProjectID
                    ASC
                ";

$binds = array(':leadId' => $_GET['id']);
$result = $db->select($query, $binds);
$json = [];

foreach ($result as $row){
    $json[] = ['id'=>$row['project_id'], 'text'=>$row['project_summary']];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

**Network output in console**

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMsb5.png
*As we can see, the searchProjectsByLeadID(id) function gets called but we get nothing back. No errors nor any values. The only thing getting transported is the first select box, which fetches lead data upon whats typed in the searchbox. *

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

Issue was called by having the SQL query looking for a LIKE rather than a DIRECT MATCH:

*WRONG*
WHERE
                        ProjectID > 0
                    AND
                        rapports_projectTBL.LeadID LIKE :leadId

*CORRECT*
WHERE
                        rapports_ProjectTBL.LeadID=:leadId